# Convert Class component into functional component React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to convert one class component into functional component , I could follow some steps to do so but I am not sure about how to change the rest of code to make it work. The part that is not clear for me is removing `setState`. I will add what I did so far at the end of this question as well.

Class component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        newTodoName: '',
        todos: todos
    };
}

generateNewId() {
    return this.state.todos.length + 1;
}

onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newTodos = this.state.todos.slice();
    newTodos.push({
        id: this.generateNewId(),
        name: this.state.newTodoName,
        complete: false
    });

    this.setState({todos: newTodos, newTodoName: ''});
}

onClick(id) {
    var todoItems = this.state.todos.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.todos.length; i++) {
        if (todoItems[i].id === id) {
            var newComplete = !todoItems[i].complete;
            todoItems[i].complete = newComplete;
        }
    }

    this.setState({
        todos: todoItems
    });
}

onChange(event) {
    this.setState({newTodoName: event.target.value});
}
```

What I did so far:

```
function App(props) {

const [newTodoName,setName] = useState("");
const [todos,setArray] = useState(todos);


const generateNewId() = () => {
    return setArray(todos.length + 1)
}

const onSubmit() = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newTodos = todos.slice();
    var id =
    newTodos.push({
        id: generateNewId(),
        name: newTodoName,
        complete: false
    });

    this.setState({todos: newTodos, newTodoName: ''});
}

  const onClick() = (id) => {
    var todoItems = todos.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
        if (todoItems[i].id === id) {
            var newComplete = !todoItems[i].complete;
            todoItems[i].complete = newComplete;
        }
    }

    this.setState({
        todos: todoItems
    });
}

const onChange() = (event) =>{
    this.setState({newTodoName: event.target.value});
}
```

How can I convert this class component into functional component?

Comment: `const [todos,setArray] = useState(todos);` makes no sense. If `todos` is a hardcoded array, call it differently. For example: `const [todos,setArray] = useState(originalTodos);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your states should be declared like this

```
const [newTodoName, setNewTodoName] = useState("");
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(todoProps);
```

If you want to change a state, you shouldn't use `this.setState(...)`, but

```
setNewTodoName("your string")
setTodos(YourTodos)
```

Edit:
Here is your code transformed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sid-09myu?file=/src/App.js:0-2376

Comment: I have some difficulty to convert the rest of code as well. It is not just `setState`. Could you write the whole converted component code. Thanks

Comment: @Tjax, can you show me your whole code on codesandbox.io please?

Comment: I added the whole code. There are two more small components as well. https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-torvalds-yu5wn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hello @Tjax : https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sid-09myu?file=/src/App.js there are still some improvements to make, but i'll let you finish to get your hands dirty. Don't forget to mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely accept your answer. When I add new object , there is no name for new object and when I mark it as complete, it removes new objects? Could you please check for these two error as well.